# Go to last line with data, Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there any button combination to jump directly to the last line containing data in Excel rather than scrolling through thousands of lines?

Comment: `Control End` will take you to the last cell that *has* had data in it, then you can `Home` to the beginning of the line... it remembers deleted data thought... however this seems a bit off topic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can also try CTRL+Down Arrow key.  This will take you to the last non-empty cell in the column.  CTRL+Up arrow key will bring you back up to the top.

Comment: It works with selection too: Select a row and then do Ctrl + Shift + Up/Down Arrow to select everything between the row and the first/last row with data.

Comment: Worth noting that "will take you to the last non-empty cell in the column" is not strictly correct. It will take you to the *next* (NOT last) instance where the cell state of containing data changes. If the current cell has data, it will take you to the *next empty* cell, not the last non-empty cell in the column. If the current cell has no data, it will take you to the next non-empty cell.