# Why does Ctrl-Down Arrow in Excel take me to row 1048576?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel-2013

When I use `Ctrl-Down Arrow` in Excel 2013 (as described in [Go to last line with data, Excel 2007](https://superuser.com/questions/427265/go-to-last-line-with-data-excel-2007)) I am taken well past the last line of data (about 1700 rows) all the way to row 1048576 - why might this be happening and what can I do to stop it so that `Ctrl-Down Arrow` works as expected?

Comment: The answer to http://superuser.com/questions/432896/why-does-my-excel-document-have-960-000-empty-rows suggests that this might be caused by applying formatting to an entire column, which I would have thought would be a common practice and therefore shouldn't break navigation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all cells below the current cell **in the current column** are blank, Ctrl-down arrow will take you to the last row of the spreadsheet. To get to the last row of content in that column, you can then use Ctrl-up arrow.

Comment: Ah, that explains it! I had the cursor in cell A1 and column A is entirely empty, used only for formatting. I had misunderstood the function of Ctrl-Down Arrow, thinking it would take me to the last row that has contents in any column.

Comment: The suggestion in http://superuser.com/questions/427265/go-to-last-line-with-data-excel-2007 to use Ctrl-End followed by Home to get to the last row with data in any column works for me.

Comment: One of the most disturbing & pointless navigation jumparounds ever. And then LibreOffice emulates it, of course.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer gotta disagree with you there. I use Ctrl+arrows constantly.